# JavaFX Linechart with logarithmic axis not updating well

Tags: java, javafx, visibility, linechart

I have two linecharts in my application. One is with linear axis and the other is with logarithmic axis.
When I want so view only one series in the charts I set the other series and their data not visible so i can see only that series and i use the same method for visualize again all series too.

I've tried with threads but my problem is still there: in the chart with linear axis I don't have any problem but the logarithmic one doesn't update well the data.
Some nodes remain or are not shown, for example, it seems like the chart freeze while adding or removing visibility of data. Everything goes well only if I do a resize of the window and I don't understand why it is correlated. Here is my method to show only series with a certain name:

```
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    if (series.getName().equals(name)) {
                        series.getNode().setVisible(!series.getNode().isVisible());
                        series.getData().forEach(data -> data.getNode().setVisible(series.getNode().isVisible()));
                    }
                });
            }
    }).start();
```

Here is the class i use for the logarithmic axis:

```
public class LogarithmicAxis extends ValueAxis<Number> {

private Object currentAnimationID;
private final ChartLayoutAnimator animator = new ChartLayoutAnimator(this);
private final DoubleProperty logUpperBound = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final DoubleProperty logLowerBound = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public LogarithmicAxis() {
    super(0.0001, 1000);
    bindLogBoundsToDefaultBounds();
}

public LogarithmicAxis(double lowerBound, double upperBound) {
    super(lowerBound, upperBound);
    validateBounds(lowerBound, upperBound);
    bindLogBoundsToDefaultBounds();
}

public void setLogarithmicUpperBound(double d) {
    double nd = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(d)));
    setUpperBound(nd == d ? nd * 10 : nd);
}

/**
 * Binds logarithmic bounds with the super class bounds, consider the
 * base 10 logarithmic scale.
 */
private void bindLogBoundsToDefaultBounds() {
    logLowerBound.bind(new DoubleBinding() {
        {
            super.bind(lowerBoundProperty());
        }
        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return Math.log10(lowerBoundProperty().get());
        }
    });
    logUpperBound.bind(new DoubleBinding() {
        {
            super.bind(upperBoundProperty());
        }
        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return Math.log10(upperBoundProperty().get());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Validates the bounds by throwing an exception if the values are not
 * conform to the mathematics log interval: [0,Double.MAX_VALUE]
 *
 */
private void validateBounds(double lowerBound, double upperBound) throws IllegalLogarithmicRangeException {
    if (lowerBound < 0 || upperBound < 0 || lowerBound > upperBound) {
        throw new IllegalLogarithmicRangeException(
                "The logarithmic range should be in [0,Double.MAX_VALUE] and the lowerBound should be less than the upperBound");
    }
}

/**
 * It is used to get the list of minor tick marks position to display on the axis.
 * It's based on the number of minor tick and the logarithmic formula.
 *
 */
@Override
protected List<Number> calculateMinorTickMarks() {
    List<Number> minorTickMarksPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    return minorTickMarksPositions;
}

//Then, the calculateTickValues method

/**
 * It is used to calculate a list of all the data values for each tick mark in range,
 * represented by the second parameter. Displays one tick each power of 10.
 *
 */
@Override
protected List<Number> calculateTickValues(double length, Object range) {
    LinkedList<Number> tickPositions = new LinkedList<>();
    if (range != null) {
        double lowerBound = ((double[]) range)[0];
        double upperBound = ((double[]) range)[1];

        for (double i = Math.log10(lowerBound); i <= Math.log10(upperBound); i++) {
            tickPositions.add(Math.pow(10, i));
        }

        if (!tickPositions.isEmpty()) {
            if (tickPositions.getLast().doubleValue() != upperBound) {
                tickPositions.add(upperBound);
            }
        }
    }

    return tickPositions;
}

/**
 * The getRange provides the current range of the axis. A basic
 * implementation is to return an array of the lowerBound and upperBound
 * properties defined into the ValueAxis class.
 *
 */
@Override
protected double[] getRange() {
    return new double[]{
            getLowerBound(),
            getUpperBound()
    };
}

/**
 * The getTickMarkLabel is only used to convert the number value to a string
 * that will be displayed under the tickMark.
 *
 */
@Override
protected String getTickMarkLabel(Number value) {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    formatter.setMaximumIntegerDigits(10);
    formatter.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
    return formatter.format(value);
}

/**
 * Updates the range when data are added into the chart.
 * There is two possibilities, the axis is animated or not. The
 * simplest case is to set the lower and upper bound properties directly
 * with the new values.
 *
 */
@Override
protected void setRange(Object range, boolean animate) {
    if (range != null) {
        final double[] rangeProps = (double[]) range;
        final double lowerBound = rangeProps[0];
        final double upperBound = rangeProps[1];
        final double oldLowerBound = getLowerBound();
        setLowerBound(lowerBound);
        setUpperBound(upperBound);
        if (animate) {
            animator.stop(currentAnimationID);
            currentAnimationID = animator.animate(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                            new KeyValue(currentLowerBound, oldLowerBound)
                    ),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700),
                            new KeyValue(currentLowerBound, lowerBound)
                    )
            );
        } else {
            currentLowerBound.set(lowerBound);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Number getValueForDisplay(double displayPosition) {
    double delta = logUpperBound.get() - logLowerBound.get();
    if (getSide().isVertical()) {
        return Math.pow(10, (((displayPosition - getHeight()) / -getHeight()) * delta) + logLowerBound.get());
    } else {
        return Math.pow(10, (((displayPosition / getWidth()) * delta) + logLowerBound.get()));
    }
}

@Override
public double getDisplayPosition(Number value) {
    double delta = logUpperBound.get() - logLowerBound.get();
    double deltaV = Math.log10(value.doubleValue()) - logLowerBound.get();
    if (getSide().isVertical()) {
        return (1. - ((deltaV) / delta)) * getHeight();
    } else {
        return ((deltaV) / delta) * getWidth();
    }
}

/**
 * Exception to be thrown when a bound value isn't supported by the
 * logarithmic axis<br>
 *
 */
public static class IllegalLogarithmicRangeException extends RuntimeException {
    public IllegalLogarithmicRangeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2):

> view only one series in the charts

One way to do this is to place one series in the chart and remove all others.

To do that, don't try to hide the nodes in other series, but, instead, remove other series from the data set, the charts will update automatically.

Turn off animation on the chart if you want an instant update instead of an animated one.

```
 lineChart.setAnimated(false);
```

> I've tried with threads

I don't advise using other threads unless you really need to.

Never access data associated with the active scene graph off of the JavaFX thread.  This would include the line graph and its data.

To allow that to happen, run the logic which gets the lineChart data within the `Platform.runlater()` call, rather than accessing the `lineChart.getData()` call in your own thread as you have in your question.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        for (Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
            if (series.getName().equals(name)) {
                series.getNode().setVisible(!series.getNode().isVisible());
                series.getData().forEach(data -> data.getNode().setVisible(series.getNode().isVisible()));
            }
        }
    });
}).start();
```

But then, if you do that, the thread and runLater calls seem pointless because you could just do everything inline:

```
for (Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
    if (series.getName().equals(name)) {
        series.getNode().setVisible(!series.getNode().isVisible());
        series.getData().forEach(data -> data.getNode().setVisible(series.getNode().isVisible()));
    }
}
```

**Example Code**

I tried implementing a kind of "only include displayed series" strategy.

After implementing, I think that perhaps your original idea of hiding series by changing their visibility might be better.

It was a little bit trickier than I expected because when you only display a single series, it is colored by the default coloring scheme, where the colors are assigned by the sequential position of the series in the data.  So, when you only display one series instead of many, the color of the series displayed actually changes, unless you override the default color scheme.

You can override that in a CSS style sheet, but then you need to change the style sheets for each selected series so that the series color stays constant, which is a pain.

There may be a nicer way of handling this.  I thought you might just be able to set the DEFAULT_COLOR_ looked up color via setStyle in code, but I couldn't get that to work, so I just went with the pretty ugly style sheet code.

I also didn't integrate the logarithmic axis, because (as far as I can tell) the axis type should really have no bearing on this.

Another trick to this was that animated must be turned off for it to work, otherwise, the observer for the animated data will be fired while resetting the series data.  It will think there is duplicated data series being added (which there isn't really, so that is a strange implementation quirk of the chart animation logic).

Anyway, for what it's worth, I provided the code I came up with.

If no toggles are set, it shows all series.  If a toggle is set, it only shows the series corresponding to that toggle.

[image: all series]

[image: selected series]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class SeriesSelectionApp extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_SERIES = 3;
    private static final int NUM_DATA_PER_SERIES = 10;
    private static final int DATA_MIN_VALUE = 5;
    private static final int DATA_MAX_VALUE = 10;

    private static final String[] seriesColors = new String[] {
            "red", "green", "blue"
    };

    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> data = generateData();

        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(
                new NumberAxis(0, NUM_DATA_PER_SERIES, 1),
                new NumberAxis(0, DATA_MAX_VALUE, 1)
        );
        lineChart.getData().setAll(data);
        lineChart.setAnimated(false);
        setDefaultChartSeriesColors(lineChart);

        HBox controls = new HBox(10);
        ToggleGroup seriesSelectionToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SERIES; i++) {
            ToggleButton showSeriesToggleButton = new ToggleButton("Series " + (i+1));
            showSeriesToggleButton.setToggleGroup(seriesSelectionToggleGroup);
            showSeriesToggleButton.setUserData(i+1);

            controls.getChildren().add(showSeriesToggleButton);
        }

        seriesSelectionToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, selectedToggle) -> {
            lineChart.getData().clear();
            if (selectedToggle == null) {
                lineChart.getData().addAll(data);
                setDefaultChartSeriesColors(lineChart);
            } else {
                int selectedSeriesNum = (int) selectedToggle.getUserData();
                lineChart.getData().add(data.get(selectedSeriesNum - 1));
                setSpecificChartSeriesColor(lineChart, selectedSeriesNum);
            }
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, controls, lineChart);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void setDefaultChartSeriesColors(LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart) {
        lineChart.getStylesheets().setAll(
                """
                data:text/css,
                .default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: red, white; }
                .default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: green, white; }
                .default-color2.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: blue, white; }
                .default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: red; }
                .default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: green; }
                .default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: blue; }
                """
        );
    }

    private void setSpecificChartSeriesColor(LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart, int seriesNum) {
        lineChart.getStylesheets().setAll(
                """
                data:text/css,
                .default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: MY_COLOR, white; }
                .default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: MY_COLOR; }
                """.replaceAll("MY_COLOR", getSeriesColor(seriesNum))
        );
    }

    private String getSeriesColor(int seriesNum) {
        return seriesColors[(seriesNum - 1) % seriesColors.length];
    }

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> generateData() {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int seriesNum = 0; seriesNum < NUM_SERIES; seriesNum++) {
            ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> seriesData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_DATA_PER_SERIES; x++) {
                int y = random.nextInt(DATA_MAX_VALUE - DATA_MIN_VALUE) + DATA_MIN_VALUE;
                XYChart.Data<Number, Number> dataItem = new XYChart.Data<>(x, y);
                seriesData.add(dataItem);
            }

            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>("Series " + (seriesNum + 1), seriesData);
            allData.add(series);
        }

        return allData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already set the two chart as not animated but it doesn't change anything. The solution of adding and removing data to/from the chart is not the best solution for me because I have to manage a large set of data, at a single time in both charts and not only with a series at time but also all of them at a single time... anyway I thank you so much for the answer and the time spent for it!

Comment: _I have to manage a large set of data_ core fx charts is not really meant for large sets (there are known problems with updating the data, mixture of data and view, not really configurable .. ), you might consider looking into 3rd party implementations

Comment: @GRETA you will get more applicable answers and make the best use of time if you are more specific in your questions fully outlining the problem you are trying to solve and provide an [mcve].